# Laravel 4 route with unlimited number of parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm trying to create a dynamic route for an unlimited number of URL levels.

Here's my current route

```
Route::get('{pageLink}', array('uses' => 'SiteController@getPage'));
```

This works for the first level. So a URL like something.com/foo/ would work. But if I had something like something.com/foo/bar/ it wouldn't catch that URL. I need it to match unlimited levels. That way in my controller it'll get me a variable of whatever the entire link is.

I know I could do

```
Route::get('{pageLink}', array('uses' => 'SiteController@getPage'));
Route::get('{pageLink}/{pageLink2}', array('uses' => 'SiteController@getPage'));
Route::get('{pageLink}/{pageLink2}/{pageLink3}', array('uses' => 'SiteController@getPage'));
```

But that just seems like an overkill. Is there a better way to do this so it'll match to the end of the URL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
//routes.php
Route::get('{pageLink}/{otherLinks?}', 'SiteController@getPage')->where('otherLinks', '(.*)');
```

Remember to put the above on the very end (bottom) of routes.php file as it is like a 'catch all' route, so you have to have all the 'more specific' routes defined first.

```
//controller 
class SiteController extends BaseController {

    public function getPage($pageLink, $otherLinks = null)
    {
        if($otherLinks) 
        {
            $otherLinks = explode('/', $otherLinks);
            //do stuff 
        }
    }

}
```

This approach should let you use unlimited amount of params, so this is what you seem to need.

Comment: What exactly does the ? in {} mean?

Comment: It means it's optional @Riki137

Comment: Nice approach, valid even for Laravel 5. Can you please explain how does where('otherLinks', '(.*)') work?

Answer (score 1):

@Fusion
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing

You may constrain the format of your route parameters using the where method on a route instance. The `where` method accepts the name of the parameter and a regular expression defining how the parameter should be constrained. so `{id}` is a route parameter , and `->where('id', '[0-9]+')` is a regex expression for this parameter. If u need to use more than parameters you can do something like this :

```
Route::get('user/{id}/{id2}', function ($id) { })->where('id', '[0-9]+')->where('id2', '[[0-9]+]');


    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) {

    })->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Comment: Add comments and explain your answer.

Comment: You may constrain the format of your route parameters using the where method on a route instance. The where method accepts the name of the parameter and a regular expression defining how the parameter should be constrained.

so {id} is  a route parameter , and ->where('id', '[0-9]+') is a regex expression for this parameter.

If u need to use more than parameters you can do something like this :

Route::get('user/{id}/{id2}', function ($id) {

})->where('id', '[0-9]+')->where('id2', '[[0-9]+]');