# How to make a url with parameters? Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I need to make a url with undetermined number of parameters. So I want to make search.

For example:

```
test.com/recipes/{category?}/{country?}/{ingredients?}/{eingredients?}

test.com/breakfast/france/ingredients/45/147/180/eingredients/2/79/205
test.com/france/eingredients/2/79/205
test.com/breakfast/ingredients/45/147/180
test.com/breakfast
```

ingredients and eingredients are arrays.

ingredients - included in the recipe (ids)
eingredients - excluded from the recipe (ids)

I have an idea:

```
Route::get('/recipes/{category?}/{country?}/{ingredients?}/{eingredients?}', 'RecipeController@index')
->where(['ingredients' => '^ingredients/[0-9\/]+$', 'eingredients' => '^eingredients/[0-9\/]+$']);
```

but it does not work:

```
test.com/france/eingredients/2/79/205
```

I get page 404...

How i can make it?

P.S: I just started learning laravel.

Comment: You can't make undetermined number of parameters. And check the order. Your orders doesn't match with your routes. Even you are using wrong address.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GET parameters to feet your needs `test.com/search?country=france&category=breakfast....`
If you want url to look like `/country/***/` then you can make them, and in .htaccess file rewrite them to get parameters. And to be sure about order, in search url add some info, for example: `test.com/county/france/category/breakfast/****`

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21526071/2420002.

```
 Route::get('{pageLink}/{otherLinks?}', 'SiteController@getPage');

//controller 
class SiteController extends BaseController {

    public function getPage($pageLink, $otherLinks = null)
    {
        if($otherLinks) 
        {
            $otherLinks = explode('/', $otherLinks);
            //do stuff 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It is a good idea.

But then, too, will be divided IDS.

ingredients/45/147/180/eingredients/2/79/205
<code>
[0] = ingredients
[1] = 45
[2] = 147
[3] = 180
[4] = eingredients
[5] = ...
</code>